# Xcode not recognizing c++ syntax

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, objective-c++

I have a project in xcode where I use a c++ library, it use to work and compile correctly, but whithout any change now it won't compile telling some errors in the .h files libraries and in my view controller where I use some c++ variables, I have my file with the .mm extension and all the errors I'm having are about the c++ syntax like in the word `namespace` it tells it's `Unknown type name` or in every other line where the syntax is c++ type Xcode can't recognize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found out by my self on this page http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/631-how-to-get-c-and-objective-c-to-play-nicely-in-xcode/
The problem was that the compiler was making a mess because only the files where I used c++ code I put them the `.mm` extension and there was some files with just `.m`
By changing the extension of every file in my project to `.mm` even if it hasn't any c++ code solved the problem.